# selenium webdriver - Unable to select any of the items based upon my search using partial text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoGWf.jpg)I have scenario like below.

I would like to select some of the skills based upon my search text "Data Analytics" in naukri.com

I am unable to write down a script and select any of the items in the list.Can anyone help me on this front.I have attached the snap with the html code in this link for your reference.[HTML with the search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoGWf.jpg)

Comment: Please can you provide the HTML for the section you want to interact with and what you have tried already?

Comment: @Debasis did you try to do in 2 steps? first click on the input where is located the dropdown and the select any of the visible element findByClassname and click on it. This should work

Comment: u want all the search result through ur script?

Comment: @noor: Yes You are correct.I need all the search result through my script and also would like to select any of the visible element.I guess it will only work with using moushover.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Debasis, i already give an answer of ur question, pls check it and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

u can use contains in ur xpath like below:

after writing data in search box, try the below code:

```
Thread.sleeep(2000);
//this will show all the elements containg the data keyword.
List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='sugDrp_skill']/ul/li/div[contains(text(),'Data')]"));

for(WebElement element : elem){      

    //this will hover to ur all search result elements one by one
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
    builder.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

    //If u want to click based on condition use this
    //this will click on clinical data management search result        
    if( element.getText().equals("Clinical Data")){
        Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver); 
        builder1.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
    }

}
```

Comment: I used the same logic and it worked.Thank you very much for immediate help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It should work fine. 
(wait methods for debug only use your more suitable waiters).

```
 @Test
  public void selectSkill() {
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/");
    selectSkillByIndex(1);
  }

  public void selectSkillByIndex (int index) {
    By closeButton = By.xpath("(//span[@class='close'])[1]");
    By dropdownItems = By.xpath("//li[@class='sugTouple']");
    WebElement skillInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='skill']//input"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    skillInput.click();
    waitForCondition(10, ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(closeButton), driver);
    skillInput.sendKeys("data");
    waitForCondition(10, ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(dropdownItems), driver);
    waitFor(1000);
    action.click(driver.findElements(dropdownItems).get(index)).perform();
    action.click(driver.findElement(closeButton)).perform();
  }

  public void waitForCondition(int seconds, ExpectedCondition<?> condition, WebDriver driver) {
      Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds).ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
      wait.until(condition);
  }

  public static void waitFor(int milliseconds) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I guess its working fine.I have ran two-three times.Will let you know if i face the same issue again.Thanks,Debasis